# I got this Error "The following error appeared when setting your Matplotlib backend!!" when opening Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, importerror

So I just reinstalled Anaconda, set up my env opened Spyder and got this Error:

```
=========================================================================
NOTE: The following error appeared when setting your Matplotlib backend!!
=========================================================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\kernel.py", line 477, in _set_mpl_backend
    get_ipython().run_line_magic(magic, backend)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2314, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-109>", line 2, in matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py", line 99, in matplotlib
    gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui, str) else args.gui)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3414, in enable_matplotlib
    pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 313, in activate_matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2355, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\pylab\backend_inline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import new_figure_manager, FigureCanvasAgg # analysis: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 45, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 64, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

Comment: There is some confusion between different python versions. Note how you start off with `C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages`, but end up with `C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages`.

Comment: Please show or describe the commands you used to *set up my env [and] opened Spyder*.

Answer (score 1):

This just happend to me, it turns out that I had modified in Tools>Preferences>Terminal ipython>Graphics>Graphics output> Gtk3

change it to automatic or another, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was also facing the same issue.

Try to re-install the package:

For **Pip user**:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

For **Pip3 user**:

```
pip3 uninstall matplotlib
```

Install again:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur for individuals working with a newer version. I encountered this error when opening Spyder version 5.4.1, and it was resolved by deleting the following folder:

C:\Users\...\.matplotlib.